# Spring boot bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder and Authentication issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, passwords, bcrypt

I am configuring Spring Security for the first time, but it seems Spring can't see my client's raw password as I am getting this error.

`o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Empty encoded password`

It seems like an obvious problem, but permit me, I just can't figure it our after many attempts.
My SecurityConfig class is ...

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
@Autowired
BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {  auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

}
```

This is my UserServiceDetails Service.

public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository repo;


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    Optional<Owner> optionalUser = repo.findByUsername(username);
    optionalUser
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not 
found"));

    return optionalUser
        .map(CustomUserDetails::new).get();
    }
}
```

I do also have the following bean configured

```
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}
```

}
This is my userService.

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends Owner implements UserDetails {

public CustomUserDetails(final Owner owner) {
    super();
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    return getRoles().stream()
        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+getRoles()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

}

I surely must be missing something, but I can't seem to figure it out. From HttpRequest, I know that the password is being posted to the System, as I logged.

Comment: can you post your UserDetailService?

Comment: Did you use BCEncoder to encode the password when you persist it?

Comment: @AokoQin, I used BCrypt to Persist the password, and and got 6 character hash password in the database.

Comment: @IntegralMaster,6?Is there a length limit for password in db?It should be 60.

Comment: @slimane I have it posted, did u mean UserService? I have just edited and posted that as well.

Comment: @AokoQin, I counted it manually, it contains 60 characters. I am suspecting the problem came up during matching of passwords, and my raw password wasn't being supplied to the "matcher"

Comment: I meant this one CustomUserDetailsService?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the OptionalUser is not mapping correctly into the UserDetail object, thereby returning a new and empty UserDetail object. the following code is wrong.

```
return optionalUser
    .map(CustomUserDetails::new).get();
 }
```

So I my new UserDetailsService class is ...

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository repo;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException 
{

    Optional<Owner> optionalUser = repo.findByUsername(username);
    Owner user = optionalUser.get();

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), getAuthorities(user));
}
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Owner user) {

    return user.getRoles().stream()
        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+user.getRoles()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
}
```